# Upload images/videos to a separate server - Javascript Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor application deployed on Digital Ocean. I'd like to create a new server which will hold all images and videos. The site will be on a separate server and when the user uploads a new image/video, it will be stored in a separate server.

Any tips on how can I achieved that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: not tried this, but maybe this is a solution
https://www.npmjs.com/package/scp2

Answer (score 2):

meteor-slingshot dose this job very-well, it fits your use-case.

https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot

Comment: Can I use digitalocean on this?